# how to sort the elasticsearch data by _id

Tags: elasticsearch

right now I have a eleasticsearch existed index database, and the _id value is like "a:1", "a:2", "a:3" "a:100", right now I want to sort the es index data by _id desc. So the result sequence is like this:
a:100, a:3: a:2 a:1

my elasticsearch version is the lastest version: 8.10. After I execute the query sentence, there is a error message:

```
#! Loading the fielddata on the _id field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. If you require sorting or aggregating on this field you should also include the id in the body of your documents, and map this field as a keyword field that has [doc_values] enabled
```

This is my query sentence:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {"_doc": "desc"}
  ]
}
```

This is the index create sentence:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {"type": "text"},
      "age": {"type": "integer"},
      "type": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

After I see the error message, I change the index create sentence:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "_id": {"type": "keyword", "copy_to":"id"},
      "id": {"type": "keyword", "store":true},
      "name": {"type": "text"},
      "age": {"type": "integer"},
      "type": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

Then it has error too.

Because the existed database in the elasticsearch, the "_id" field value increased by "string:integer" style. So I want to sort the search result by "_id" field, but the new elasticsearch version do not allow to do that, so I do not know how to make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare the `_id` field in your mapping. You can only declare a custom `id` field that you also use as ID when indexing your documents. Once you do that you can sort by ID as you wish:

First create your mapping with an `id` keyword field:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "keyword"},
      "name": {"type": "text"},
      "age": {"type": "integer"},
      "type": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

Then when indexing your data also include your ID inside your document:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/a:1
{
   "id": "a:1",
   ...
}
PUT my-index/_doc/a:2
{
   "id": "a:2",
   ...
}

...

PUT my-index/_doc/a:3
{
   "id": "a:3",
   ...
}
```

Finally, you'll be able to sort on your `id` field

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {"id": "desc"}
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you're not in control of the ingestion process, you can still update your index using the `_update_by_query` API:

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "script": { 
    "source": "ctx._source.id = ctx._id"
  }
}
```

You need to make sure to add the `id` field as a keyword in your mapping **prior to** running update by query. When the process is complete, all your documents will have an `id` field that you can use to sort the data.

If new data comes in all the time, you'll need to set up an additional ingest pipeline in order to create this new field on the fly as new documents get indexed. Let me know if you need to know more about how this is set up.

Comment: Thanks very much. Actually right now I can not control the inserting data process.  So that's why I want to automatically copy the _id value to new id field. Seemed like it is impossible

Comment: It is possible with an update by query call, is it something you can do?

Comment: You means this? I can not execute this query call: I do not have the permission to do that.
PUT my-index/_doc/a:1
{
   "id": "a:1",
   ...
}

Comment: So is it possible for me to use the copy_to feature of es to copy the _id value to id?

Comment: No, not with copy_to, but with update_by_query if you're allowed to run that command

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks very much. After I execute the update_by_query sentence. Then I search it by this:

GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Then there are some error:
Fielddata is disabled on [id] in [my_index]. Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [id] in order to load field data

Comment: by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memor

Comment: Because you did not create the `id` field in your mapping **prior to** running the update as I suggested. You can then run the sort on `id.keyword` instead and it will work.

Comment: Thanks very much. I get it. But if I want to the id field type is integer, value is coming from "a:1" to 1. I jus try 

POST /my_index/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "script": { 
    "source": "ctx._source.id1 = ctx._id.split(':')[1]"
  }
}
it does not work

Comment: @Val performance wise, is using runtime field acceptable? Will it at least is better than directly sorting with _id? I am thinking if I should add a field just for `search after`.

Comment: @WeihuiGuo if you can do without runtime fields and create an optimal mapping from the start, it's always better. The solution above is only optimal to the problem at hand because the OP was not able to change the mapping or reindex his data.

Comment: @Val thank you for your prompt reply, I asked a separate question, and I wonder if you can help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77607342/4271117