# Best way to implement tiebreaker for search_after

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

The `_id` field [is restricted from use in aggregations, sorting, and scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/mapping-id-field.html). In case sorting or aggregating on the _id field is required, it is advised to duplicate the content of the `_id` field into another field that has `doc_values` enabled. I wonder what's the best way to create a copy of the _id field with `doc_values` enabled, mainly for the existing indices.

I tried using [_update_by_query suggested by Val](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77417369/4271117) and it seems to be working but if there is a new doc or update after `_update_by_query`, it'll not include the tie_breaker_id. And I'd like to avoid running `_update_by_query` for each future search. Thought about the runtime field but we have indices on elastic 6.x and it also can impact search performance.

Comment: Fortunately, I found other fields that can be used as tiebreakers, as PO doesn't want to add a new field in elastic anyway. I guess once we upgrade from 6.x to 7 or up, we can use PIT, maybe.

Answer (score -1):

In Elasticsearch, search_after is often used for paginating through search results efficiently. When you need to implement a tiebreaker to ensure consistent ordering in case of equal primary sort values, you can use a combination of the primary sort field and a tiebreaker field.

Here's an example of how you can implement a tiebreaker with search_after:

Use a Multi-field Mapping:
Define a multi-field mapping for the field you want to sort on. This involves creating two fields, one for the primary sorting and another for the tiebreaker.

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)